# How to combine multiple sources during the creation of a query?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

I want to create a query in which it loads multiple sources at a time, formats them and then combines them.

I used pipeline operators '|>' to format the sources and to simplify the process.

```
let
Source1 = Json.Document(Web.Contents(...))
    |> Table.FromRecords
    |> Table.RemoveColumns({"...", "..."})
    |> Table.ExpandListColumn(...)
    |> Table.ExpandRecordColumn("...", {"...", "...", "..."});

Source2 = Json.Document(Web.Contents(...))
    |> Table.FromRecords
    |> Table.RemoveColumns({"...", "..."})
    |> Table.ExpandListColumn(...)
    |> Table.ExpandRecordColumn("...", {"...", "...", "..."});

Combined = Table.Combine({Source1, Source2})
```

in
Combined

Power Query tells me that a comma is missing at the first '|' of the first operator. If I add one, it says that an Identifier is missing.

I can create multiple requests and then combine them, but I want to avoid this because my workstation is very slow and it will slow it down even more because of all the dependencies.

Comment: ChatGPT has just made this up and it isn't valid M. What are your data sources - are they actually JSON? Having 2 sources in 1 query will make zero difference to performance unless you're making use of buffering which I suspect you're not.

Comment: Yes, It is a JSON data source. In fact, ChatGPT suggested this syntax. Normally I use the syntax suggested by Marcus but it's very heavy and redundant. That's why I ask ChatGPT something more concise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: This notation is not supported by Power Query. You will need to use standard query syntax:

```
let
  Source1 = Json.Document(Web.Contents(...)),
  s11 = Table.FromRecords(Source1),
  s12 = Table.RemoveColumns(s11, {"...", "..."}),
  s13 = Table.ExpandListColumn(s12, ...),
  Source1T = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(s13, "...", {"...", "...", "..."}),
  Source2 = Json.Document(Web.Contents(...)),
  s21 = Table.FromRecords(Source2),
  s22 = Table.RemoveColumns(s21, {"...", "..."}),
  s23 = Table.ExpandListColumn(s22, ...),
  Source2T = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(s23, "...", {"...", "...", "..."}),
  Combined = Table.Combine({Source1T, Source2T})
in
  Combined
```

or I suppose something like this would also work:

```
let
  Source1 = 
    let 
      s10 = Json.Document(Web.Contents(...)),
      s11 = Table.FromRecords(Source1),
      s12 = Table.RemoveColumns(s11, {"...", "..."}),
      s13 = Table.ExpandListColumn(s12, ...)
    in
      Table.ExpandRecordColumn(s13, "...", {"...", "...", "..."}),
  
  Source2 = 
    let 
      s20 = Json.Document(Web.Contents(...)),
      s21 = Table.FromRecords(Source2),
      s22 = Table.RemoveColumns(s21, {"...", "..."}),
      s23 = Table.ExpandListColumn(s22, ...)
    in
      Table.ExpandRecordColumn(s23, "...", {"...", "...", "..."}),
  
  Combined = Table.Combine({Source1T, Source2T})
in
  Combined
```

Comment: It is because it is made up by ChatGPT. The operator doesn't exist in M

Comment: That explains it. I did find a "wouldn't this be nice" type article about this, but this is apparently not supported! Cheers David.

Comment: Yeah, piping would be an amazing addition. I think Ben Gribaudo wrote about it. Alas, it isn't to be.

Comment: Good to know our jobs are safe from ChatGPT for the moment.. ;)

Comment: Thanks Marcus! I was hoping to avoid this kind of syntax, which is the one I normally use, I think it's too heavy and redundant.

Comment: I recommend following David's suggestion of just having multiple queries that you join - and set the `Source1` and `Source2` queries to not be loaded. Unless you are using buffering, it will be the exact same overhead (e.g. Power Query will "manually" append the query code in the combined query).